# Add Maintenance Mode to Spring (Security) app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, maintenance-mode

I'm looking for a way to implement a Maintenance Mode in my Spring app.

While the app is in Maintenance Mode only users `role = MAINTENANCE` should be allowed to log in. Everyone else gets redirected to login page.

Right now I just built a Filter:

```
@Component
public class MaintenanceFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Autowired SettingStore settings;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(settingStore.get(MaintenanceMode.KEY).isEnabled()) {
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response; 
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response); 
        }
    }
}
```

And added it using:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // omitted other stuff
        .addFilterAfter(maintenanceFilter, SwitchUserFilter.class);
}
```

Because as far as I figured out `SwitchUserFilter` should be the last filter in Spring Security's filter chain.

Now every request gets canceled with a 503 response. Though there's no way to access the login page.

If I add a redirect to the Filter, this will result in an infinite loop, because access to login page is also denied.

Additionally I can't figure out a nice way to get the current users roles. Or should I just go with `SecurityContextHolder` ?

---

I'm looking for a way to redirect every user to the login page (maybe with a query param `?maintenance=true`) and every user with `role = MAINTENANCE` can use the application.

So the Filter / Interceptor should behave like:

```
if(maintenance.isEnabled()) {
    if(currentUser.hasRole(MAINTENANCE)) {
        // this filter does nothing
    } else {
        redirectTo(loginPage?maintenance=true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now found two similar solutions which work, but the place where I inject the code doesn't look that nice.

For both I add a custom `RequestMatcher`, which get's `@Autowired` and checks if Maintenance Mode is enabled or not.

### Solution 1:

```
@Component
public class MaintenanceRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
    @Autowired SettingStore settingStore;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return settingStore.get(MaintenanceMode.KEY).isEnabled()
    }
}
```

And in my Security Config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired MaintenanceRequestMatcher maintenanceRequestMatcher;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(maintenanceRequestMatcher).hasAuthority("MY_ROLE")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    // ...
}
```

### Solution 2:

Very similar, but uses `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole(...)`:

```
@Component
public class MaintenanceRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
    @Autowired SettingStore settingStore;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return settingStore.get(MaintenanceMode.KEY).isEnabled() && !request.isUserInRole("MY_ROLE");
    }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired MaintenanceRequestMatcher maintenanceRequestMatcher;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(maintenanceRequestMatcher).denyAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    // ...
}
```

This will perform a `denyAll()` if Maintenance Mode is enabled **and** the current user does not have `MY_ROLE`.

---

The only disadvantage is, that I cannot set a custom response. I'd prefer to return a `503 Service Unavailable`. Maybe someone can figure out how to do this.

Comment: thanks for the answer. here is a working example https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/maintainence-mode

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda of a chicken or egg dilemma, you want to show unauthorized users a "we're in maintenance mode ..." message, while allow authorized users to login, but you don't know if they are authorized until they log in. Ideally it would be nice to have this in some sort of filter, but I found in practice it was easier for me to solve a similar issue by putting the logic after login, like in the `UserDetailsService`.

Here's how I solved it on a project. When I'm in maintenance mode, I set a flag for the view to show the "we're in maintenance mode .." message, in a global header or on the login page. So users, regardless of who they are know it's maintenance mode. Login should work as normal.

After user is authenticated, and in my custom `UserDetailsService`, where their user details are loaded with their roles, I do the following:

```
// if we're in maintenance mode and does not have correct role
if(maintenance.isEnabled() && !loadedUser.hasRole(MAINTENANCE)) {
  throw new UnauthorizedException(..)
}
// else continue as normal
```

It's not pretty, but it was simple to understand (which I think is good for security configuration stuff) and it works.

Update:

> With you solution I'd have to destroy everyone's session, else a user
>   which was logged in before maintenance mode was enabled, is still able
>   to work with the system

On our project we don't allow any users to be logged in while in maintenance mode. An admin, kicks off a task which enables "maintenance..." msg, with a count down, then at the end, we expire everyone's session using [`SessionRegistry`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#list-authenticated-principals).

Comment: With you solution I'd have to destroy everyone's session, else a user which was logged in before maintenance mode was enabled, is still able to work with the system. `...` I just wonder how Spring's login interceptor works. This does exactly the job: If a user is not authenticated when calling a resource, then he get's redirected to login page. It's kinda the same what I want/need.

Answer (score 0):

I was a similar situation and found this answer is helpful. I followed the second approach and also managed to return custom response.

Here is what I have done to return the custom response.

1- Define a controller method that returns the needed custom response.

```
@RestController
public class CustomAccessDeniedController {
    
    @GetMapping("/access-denied")
    public String getAccessDeniedResponse() {
        return "my-access-denied-page";
    }
}
```

2- In your security context, you should permit this URL to be accessible.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/access-denied").permitAll()
```

3- Create a custom access denied exception handler

```
@Component
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Autowired
    private SettingStore settingStore;
    
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        if(settingStore.get(MaintenanceMode.KEY).isEnabled()) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/access-denied");
        }
    }
}
```

4- Register the custom access denier exception handler in the security config

```
    @Autowired
    private CustomAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;


    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
```